# php array element to database

Tags: arrays, json

why this query is inserted multiple times i just wrote one insert command but it's inserted `$lat`'s length times. How can i solve this problem guys?

```
<?php
$latLngs = json_decode($_POST['latLngs']);
$lat = array();
$lng = array();
foreach ($latLngs as $obj){
    $lat[] = $obj->lat;
    $lng[] = $obj->lng;
}
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect");
@mysql_select_db("beta") or die("cannot select db");
for($i=0; $i<count(latLngs);i++)
{
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO belcheer(username,lat, lng) VALUES('user','$lat[$i]','$lng[$i]')");
    if (!$result){
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
@mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Updated!
It's still not correctly
[same values inserted many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr7BC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are having some errors in your second for loop. You are missing `$` with `count(latlngs)` and `i++`

```
<?php
$latLngs = json_decode($_POST['latLngs']);
$lat = array();
$lng = array();
foreach ($latLngs as $obj){
    $lat[] = $obj->lat;
    $lng[] = $obj->lng;
}
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect");
@mysql_select_db("beta") or die("cannot select db");
for($i=0; $i<count($latLngs);$i++)
{
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO belcheer(username,lat, lng) VALUES('user','$lat[$i]','$lng[$i]')");
    if (!$result){
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
@mysql_close($link);
?>
```

also you don't need to have too much code. You can use the following code:

```
<?php
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect");
@mysql_select_db("beta") or die("cannot select db");

$latLngs = json_decode($_POST['latLngs']);
foreach ($latLngs as $obj){
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO belcheer(username,lat, lng) VALUES('user','".$obj->lat."','".$obj->lng."')");

    if (!$result)
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

@mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. But it is still not correctly working. It inserted same value multiple times. You can see screenshot on my post. I just updated my post.

Comment: Your data is containing duplicate data :) can you verify this thing ?

Comment: Yes i checked many times. But it's insert data $latLngs's square times. I mean when $latLngs is equal 5, database recorded 25 data. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you do `print_r($_POST['latLngs'])` and share the result so that we can troubleshoot the problem ?